# How to retrieve the count of distinct rows with some event occurring on consecutive days

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns: date, event_name, video_id and user_id.

I need to write a query that will return the number of users who viewed at least one video in a given day and the number of those users who returned the next day to view at least one video. The video_play event signifies that a video was played by a user.

Here's some sample data upon which I need to base my query:

```
date            event_name      video_id    user_id
2018-01-01      video_play      51651561651 989189198
2018-01-01      video_play      98121651656 561884864
2018-01-01      video_play      78918918918 561884864
2018-01-01      create_video    32156541355 153215651
2018-01-01      create_video    87351531311 232135135
2018-01-02      create_video    51651561651 489846581
2018-01-02      video_play      12315315352 561884864
2018-01-02      create_video    32156541355 321351351
2018-01-02      create_video    87351531311 231513515
2018-01-02      video_play      98191891894 615616516
```

This query completes the first half of the querying task, but I cannot figure out the second half:

```
SELECT date
    , COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users_view_videos
    FROM clickstream_video
    WHERE event_name = 'video_play'
    GROUP BY date;
```

This is how the output should look:

```
date        users_view_videos   users_view_next_day
2018-01-01  2                   1
2018-01-02  2                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
SELECT x.date
     , x.user_id
     , y.event_name
  FROM clickstream_video x
  LEFT
  JOIN clickstream_video y
    ON y.date = x.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND y.user_id = x.user_id
WHERE x.event_name = 'video_play';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The output still isn't coming in right. I need the count of distinct user_ids whose event_name = 'video_play' on: 2018-01-01 AND 2018-01-02. Any thoughts?

Comment: I got it to work! But now I'm having trouble combining this query with my other query to produce the desired output format. I keep getting a ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row error, and am not sure how to rectify.

Comment: There's no subquery required here.